# TinyMCE Template

Tags: jquery, tinymce, cakephp-1.3

Is it possible to insert a jQuery script in tinyMCE template_templates block?

here is the template_templates block

```
template_templates : [
    {
            title : "Editor Details",
            src : "editor_details.htm",
            description : "Adds Editors Name and Staff ID"
    }
]
```

and i want to put jQuery in here

```
template_templates : [
  //jQuery
]
```

need some help here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.  As far as I know it can be a single statement only (semicolons between [] produce error).  For more complicated code, you can enclose it in a function:

```
template_templates : [
    function() {
        //jQuery code here
    }
]
```

Or, depending on what you want to achieve, you can put there a variable, and its value can be computed outside of this object.